# Given vertical asymptotes, slant asymptote, and a hole, find and graph the polynomial

Tags: polynomials

- Vertical Asymtotes: $x=4, -4$
- Slant Asymtote:  $y=x+2$
- Hole: $x=5$

Comment: You mean rational function, I assume, not polynomial?  Also you're supposed to say what you already know and what you've tried.

Comment: yeah, sorry, this is my first time posting here

Answer (score 0):

The rational function with the vertical asymtotes 4 and -4, the slant asymtote $x+2$, and the hole 5, has the form

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2(x+2)(x-5)}{(x^2-16)(x-5)}=\frac{x^4-3x^3-10x^2}{x^3-5x^2-16x+80}$$

[image]

Note that the functions satisfying above conditions are not unique.